# minikube service not reachable

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to deploy a service on minikube but it is not reachable.
Service is not reachable from my localhost 'http://127.0.0.1:9000'

```
 minio kubectl get services
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes      ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          39m
minio-service   LoadBalancer   10.103.10.132   127.0.0.1     9000:31614/TCP   29m
```

minio service yaml file:

```
metadata:
  name: minio-service
  namespace: default
  uid: 4a5fd6e9-12d7-4418-aa95-1002777d1e2e
  resourceVersion: '1310'
  creationTimestamp: '2022-02-17T13:12:33Z'
  managedFields:
    - manager: kubectl-create
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2022-02-17T13:12:33Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:spec:
          f:allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: {}
          f:externalTrafficPolicy: {}
          f:internalTrafficPolicy: {}
          f:ports:
            .: {}
            k:{"port":9000,"protocol":"TCP"}:
              .: {}
              f:port: {}
              f:protocol: {}
              f:targetPort: {}
          f:selector: {}
          f:sessionAffinity: {}
          f:type: {}
    - manager: minikube
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2022-02-17T13:21:18Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:status:
          f:loadBalancer:
            f:ingress: {}
      subresource: status
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
      nodePort: 31614
  selector:
    app: minio
  clusterIP: 10.103.10.132
  clusterIPs:
    - 10.103.10.132
  type: LoadBalancer
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 127.0.0.1
```

As per the command: `minikube service minio-service --url` but when I try to access this from the browser I get a site cannot be reached error.
Would you help me please ? thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: What's the error that comes back?

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble with forwarding ports, you can give [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod) a try to see if the application is actually listening. If you can talk to minio, then you can focus on the minikube configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Kubernetes service from docker desktop instead of minikube its much easier and use Type: Loadbalancer in service